# How to scroll To next item on a button click using FlatList in React Native?

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I have an array of months which I am using to display months using a horizontal FlatList. I want the months to change using 2 buttons that are forward button to change the month in increasing order i.e from January to February and so on and a back button to change the month backwards i.e from January to December.

[image]
How can I make the buttons do so. Below monthName is an array that contains all the month names.

```
<ScrollView style={{flexGrow: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', height: hp('130')}}>
          <View
            style={{
justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          width: wp('48'),
        }}>
        <FlatList
          data={monthName}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={(month, index) => (
            <View>
              <Months
                showMonth={month.item}
                id={month.id}
                refer={flatRef}
              />
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
          horizontal
          // snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').width}
          snapToAlignment={'center'}
          ref={(node) => (flatRef = node)}
        />
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          width: wp('12'),
        }}>
        {/* {} */}
        <IonIcons.Button  --> the button that makes the month increment.
          name="arrow-forward"
          size={25}
          backgroundColor="white"
          color="black"
          // onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}
          onPress={() => {
            flatRef.scrollToIndex({index: ?});
          }}
        />
      </View>
</View>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using a `FlatList` I would suggest you to make a `state` variable and execute it like this

Working example - [Here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/flatlist-scroll-example)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

...

  const [SelectMonth, SetSelectMonth] = React.useState(monthName[0]);

  const NextPress = () => {
    if (SelectMonth.id !== 12) {
      let temp = monthName.find((c) => c.id === SelectMonth.id + 1);
      if (temp) {
        SetSelectMonth(temp);
      }
    }
  };

  const PrevPress = () => {
    if (SelectMonth.id !== 1) {
      let temp = monthName.find((c) => c.id === SelectMonth.id - 1);
      if (temp) {
        SetSelectMonth(temp);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.CalenderBox}>
        <AntDesign
          name="caretleft"
          size={30}
          color="black"
          onPress={() => PrevPress()}
        />

        <View style={styles.MonthNameBox}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 24 }}>
            {SelectMonth.name}
          </Text>
        </View>

        <AntDesign
          name="caretright"
          size={30}
          color="black"
          onPress={() => NextPress()}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 4):

try to access ref using `current` and it should work

```
this.flatRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: monthName.length > this.state.currentindex ? this.state.currentindex++ : this.state.currentindex });
```

Comment: I want the index : value to basically increment so that I could scroll from jan to feb, feb to march and so on....

Comment: for that you have to store current index in state and on click you have to pass index++

Answer (score 1):

```js
 import React, { useRef } from 'react';
    import {
        FlatList,
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        TouchableOpacity,
        View
    } from 'react-native';
    import { wp } from '../../constants/scaling';
    import { colors } from '../../constants/theme';
    import bookingprocess from '../../data/BookingProcess';
    import { textStyles } from '../../styles/textStyles';
    import { RFValue } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
    import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
    
    const BookingProcess = ({}) => {
        const flatListRef = useRef(FlatList);
        const nextPress = index => {
            if (index <= 2) {
                flatListRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({
                    animated: true,
                    index: index + 1
                });
            }
        };
        const backPress = index => {
            if (index >= 1) {
                flatListRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({
                    animated: true,
                    index: index - 1
                });
            }
        };
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    ...styles.cardView,
                    padding: 0,
                    elevation: 0,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#f2f2f2',
                    overflow: 'hidden'
                }}>
                <View
                    style={{
                        padding: wp(2),
                        backgroundColor: colors.primaryColor
                    }}>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            ...textStyles.heading,
                            color: '#fff'
                        }}>
                        Booking Process
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        ...textStyles.mediumheading,
                        padding: wp(2),
                        paddingBottom: 0
                    }}>
                    You can reserve your parking slot in advance. Please follow
                    these four simple steps to book your parking slot.
                </Text>
                <FlatList
                    data={bookingprocess}
                    horizontal={true}
                    ref={flatListRef}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ padding: wp(2) }}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                        return (
                            <View style={styles.innerCard}>
                                {item.image}
                                <View style={styles.ButtonBox}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => backPress(index)}
                                        style={{
                                            backgroundColor: colors.secondaryColor,
                                            borderRadius: wp(50)
                                        }}>
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="leftcircle"
                                            size={RFValue(25)}
                                            color={colors.primaryColor}
                                        />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => nextPress(index)}
                                        style={{
                                            backgroundColor: colors.secondaryColor,
                                            borderRadius: wp(50)
                                        }}>
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="rightcircle"
                                            size={RFValue(25)}
                                            color={colors.primaryColor}
                                        />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.innercardHeaderView}>
                                    <Text style={styles.headingTextNumber}>
                                        {item.id}. {item.title}
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
    
                                <Text style={styles.description}>
                                    {item.description}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    };
    
    export default BookingProcess;
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        cardView: {
            backgroundColor: colors.white,
            margin: wp(2),
            elevation: 4,
            borderRadius: wp(2),
            padding: wp(2),
            width: wp(94)
        },
        innerCard: {
            margin: wp(2),
            borderRadius: wp(2),
            padding: wp(0),
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingHorizontal: 0,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: wp(90),
            elevation: 5,
            marginLeft: 0,
            padding: wp(2),
            backgroundColor: '#fff'
        },
        ButtonBox: {
            position: 'absolute',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            right: 0,
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            width: wp(20),
            padding: wp(2)
        },
        innercardHeaderView: {
            backgroundColor: '#0000',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            padding: wp(2),
            paddingBottom: 0,
            alignItems: 'center'
        },
        headingTextNumber: {
            ...textStyles.heading,
            color: colors.primaryColor,
            textAlign: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            textAlignVertical: 'center'
        },
        description: {
            ...textStyles.mediumheading,
            paddingHorizontal: wp(2),
            textAlign: 'justify'
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide some guidance instead of a huge block of sample code without any explanation?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).